# Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds

Tags: modelica, lookup-tables

I want to connect the output of a Combitable to the signal current source as shown in the code below, but it is not possible because the output of table is an array but the input of current source is a scalar.

```
model TableTest
  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds combiTable1Ds1(table = [0, 0; 1, 1; 2, 4; 4, 16])  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-4, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k = -5)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-46, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SignalCurrent signalCurrent1 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {48, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
equation
  connect(const.y, combiTable1Ds1.u) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-35, 0}, {-17, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));end TableTest;
```

Comment: By the way, there also is Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.TableCurrent doing a similar job if you stick to linear interpolation and have time as independent table variable.

Answer (score 6):

In your case, the `CombiTable1Ds` only has one output in its vector. Simply connect it to the current source with:

```
connect(combiTable1Ds1.y[1], signalCurrent1.u);
```

If you use Dymola, when you draw a connection select `y[1]` instead of the default `y[:]`

Best regards
Rene Just Nielsen