# OpenModelica: How to create a custom periodic voltage source?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm using OpenModelica 1.19.2 on Ubuntu 20.04, and I was wondering how I can create a custom periodic voltage source, with values read from an external file.

I noticed that there's the option of a TableVoltage, which takes a two-column table as input, and uses linear interpolation/extrapolation. I was hoping that this might have similar possibilities as CombiTable1D, in that you can specify a file name and extrapolation options, but that doesn't work.

Is there some way to achieve this behaviour? For example, would it be possible to generate a table using CombiTable1D and use this as an input for TableVoltage? And if so, how would I go about that? As a first guess, I tried

```
Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1D myTable(fileName = "inputFile.txt", extrapolation = 3);
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.TableVoltage myVoltage(table = myTable);
```

but apparently that's not the right way:

```
Translation Error: Dimension 1 of ‘table‘ could not be deduced from the component's binding equation myTable[<myVoltage, myVoltage>]).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the CombiTable is a good idea as it provides a lot of functionality related to inter-/extrapolation. But you cannot pass the table object (`myTable`) to `TableVoltage`. Instead, usually connections are created between the objects. This sets the output `myTable.y` to the desired value(*).

This is done in the following example, which you should be able to directly copy into your Modelica code editor:

```
model SignalSource
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable combiTimeTable(
    tableOnFile=true,
    tableName="voltage",
    fileName="inputFile.txt",
    extrapolation=Modelica.Blocks.Types.Extrapolation.Periodic)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,-10},{-40,10}})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SignalVoltage signalVoltage
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{10,-10},{-10,10}}, rotation=90)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{30,-40},{50,-20}})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor resistor(R=10)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=270,
        origin={80,0})));
equation 
  connect(resistor.p, signalVoltage.p) annotation (Line(points={{80,10},{80,20},{0,20},{0,10}}, color={0,0,255}));
  connect(signalVoltage.n, ground.p) annotation (Line(points={{0,-10},{0,-20},{40,-20}}, color={0,0,255}));
  connect(ground.p, resistor.n) annotation (Line(points={{40,-20},{80,-20},{80,-10}}, color={0,0,255}));
  connect(combiTimeTable.y[1], signalVoltage.v)
    annotation (Line(points={{-39,0},{-25.5,0},{-25.5,6.66134e-16},{-12,6.66134e-16}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")), experiment(StopTime=10));
end SignalSource;
```

If you then add a file `inputFile.txt` with the following content:

```
#1
double voltage(6,2)
  0   0
  1   0
  1   1
  2   4
  3   9
  4  16
```

to the working directory(**), the model should provide the following result:

[image: Voltage and current through resistor]

(*): An alternative to having connect statements, for this example would be adding the equation `signalVoltage.v = combiTimeTable.y[1];`, but usually the graphical variant is preferred.
(**): As an alternative you can use any local path, but you need to specify it in the parameters of the combiTable.

Comment: Awesome, that works, thanks a million! Funny, I tried something like this earlier, based on the post below, but that gave me a warning (Variable resistor.p.v. does not have any remaining equations to be solved in), and no output. Probably did something wrong in the connections part... Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165438/modelica-blocks-tables-combitable1ds